# Coloured box over certain words in R Studio script file

Tags: r, rstudio

Not sure why but in some of my R Scripts a coloured box is appearing over random words within ""

For example:
[image: The word blue is highlighted. Totally unclear why]

If I just write the word *blue* then it appears normally. Only gets this box over it when in quotation marks.

In a different R script it is happening with the "peru"[image]

Dont believe I have changed any settings. Seems to persist even if I clear the global environment.

Comment: Thats the [new feature](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/) of Rstudio IDE editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blue` and `peru` are both colors as you can verify in

```
plot(1:3, col = "peru", pch = 15, type = "b", lwd = 3)
```

So RStudio is just helping you by displaying the color refrerenced in the code

Comment: Relevant option appears to be:
Code editor can show previews of color in strings (R named colors e.g. “tomato3” or of the forms “#rgb”, “#rrggbb”, “#rrggbbaa”) when Options > Code > Display > [ ] enable preview of named and hexadecimal colors is checked.